# Confusion with NOT EXISTS and subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem understanding how the combination of `NOT EXISTS` and subqueries works.

I understand that by adding `NOT EXISTS`, the query will return all the rows the subquery will not. What I don't understand is how it works when we use it in the following case.

```
+-------------+--------+
| id_employee | salary |
+-------------+--------+
| E001        |   1000 |
| E002        |   1001 |
| E003        |    999 |
| E004        |   1001 |
+-------------+--------+
```

And try the following query:

```
SELECT E.id_employee, E.salary
FROM Employees E
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT F.id_employee
    FROM Employees F
    WHERE F.salary > E.salary
);
```

Which returns:

```
+-------------+--------+
| id_employee | salary |
+-------------+--------+
| E002        |   1001 |
| E004        |   1001 |
+-------------+--------+
```

Well, I don't really get to understand how the `F.salary > E.salary` comparison works, because if it compares row by row the two tables (which are the same), doesn't make sense to me to return any row at all.

Could you give me any hint on how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` is usually used with a Correlated Subquery, i.e. there's a relation between the Outer and the Inner query (and you can't run the subquery code on its own without a "table not found" error). Your example is correlated but in a strange way.

Logically it's processed like this:

for each row in the employee table run following query:

```
SELECT F.id_employee
FROM Employees F
WHERE F.salary > <salary of the current row>
```

If this query doesn't return any row (i.e. there's no row with a salary greater than the current one) the `NOT EXISTS` evaluates to true and returns this row from the employee table.

In fact this query returns the rows with the lowest salary.

A Correlated `EXISTS` is quite similar to a `JOIN` and the `NOT EXISTS` is a kind of anti-JOIN, only those rows which can't be joined will be returned. And this is the common usage, find rows with values which don't exists in the 2nd table, e.g find employees with an invalid/non-existing department number

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees E
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Departments D
    WHERE E.department_number = D.department_number
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying no other condition in your subquery than:

```
 F.salary > E.salary
```

You are getting any row from `E` where there is no other entry in `F` that has a salary greater then it. Since both `E002` and `E004` have a salary of `1001`, and no one else has a salary greater then `1001`, both `E002` and `E004` are returned.

If you change your `WHERE` to be:

```
F.salary >= E.salary
```

You will get no records returns as everyone has a salary that is less then or equal to another employee's salary.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, `WHERE` clause is evaluated for each row. `WHERE` clause will return only those rows for which predicate evaluates to `TRUE`. Your predicate is

```
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT F.id_employee
    FROM Employees F
    WHERE F.salary > E.salary
);
```

So resultset will contain only rows where this predicate is evaluated to `TRUE`. For row 1 which salary is 1000 there exists rows which salary is bigger, so for this row predicate is `FALSE` and it is eliminated from resultset. Fom second row salary is 1001 and there is no other rows where salary is greater so for this row predicate evaluates to `TRUE` and this row will be in resultset.